# Replace After in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string like this

```
"test, test2, test2, test4"
```

i want replace after each  `','` and at first char some other chars my result must show like this

"XXXtest, XXXtest2, XXXtest2, XXXtest4"

with which javascript function can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic regex replace should work:

```
string.replace(/, /g, ', XXX');
```

We're searching for all (`g` flag) commas followed by a space (`,`) and replacing them with a comma, followed by a space, followed by what you want (`, XXX`).

This won't replace the first occurrence of `test` (because the string doesn't start with a comma), so you have to do add your replacement string to the beginning of the result.

```
'XXX' + string.replace(/, /g, ', XXX');
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QGURA/1/

Answer (score 1):

function replace would do that

```
var s = "test, test2, test2, test4";
var r = 'XXX'+s.replace(/,\s/g, ', XXX');
```

Comment: the result looks like "XXXtest, XXXtest2, test2, test4"